# Comparing geometric brownian motion at stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Suppose we have 2 geometric brownian motions, $(X^{(1)}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and  $(X^{(2)}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ driven by the same Brownian motion and started at the same position.  Suppose they have the same volatility $\sigma$ but the drifts are such that $\mu_2 \geq \mu_1$.  Then it is not hard to show that $\mathbb{P}[X^{(1)}_t \leq X^{(2)}_t, \forall t \geq 0] = 1.$  So one process dominates the other.

Then, does that imply for **any** stopping time (w.r.t. the filtration generated by the Brownian motion) $\tau$:

a)$\mathbb{P}[X^{(1)}_\tau \leq X^{(2)}_{\tau}] = 1$?

b)$\mathbb{E}[X^{(1)}_\tau] \leq \mathbb{E}[X^{(2)}_{\tau}]$?

Of course a) implies b) but I do not know if a) is true.

Comment: Yes, a) is true, and why not?

Comment: Any idea on how to prove such a statement?

Comment: Oh it is actually very obvious.  My bad.